# How to call a Jquery function in Ajax callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, getusermedia

I have Two different file I am calling a jquery Function

which is created in my File2.js from file1.php

#file1.php
In my first file I am calling a Jquery Function in ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" autoplay></video>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    getusermedia();
    function getusermedia(media){
        $.ajax({
            url:"getusermedia.js",
            method:"POST",
            data:{media},
            success:function(data){
                $("#video").html(data);
            }
        })
    }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#file2.js
Here is my jquery Code

```
const mediaStreamConstraints = {
  video: true,
  audio: true
};
const localVideo = document.querySelector('video');
let localStream;
function gotLocalMediaStream(mediaStream) {
  localStream = mediaStream;
  localVideo.srcObject = mediaStream;
}
function handleLocalMediaStreamError(error) {
  console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaStreamConstraints)
  .then(gotLocalMediaStream).catch(handleLocalMediaStreamError);
```

I am getting the answer when

I put this both code in single file

but in two different file Its not responding

Comment: your not importing file2.js, nor will posting to getusermedia.js work

Comment: Sending a POST to a `.js` file doesn't execute the JavaScript.

Comment: You can use `$.getScript()` to load a `.js` file using AJAX. But how is the `media` parameter supposed to be used by the script?

Answer (score 0):

ajax call could not find a html element `const localVideo = document.querySelector('video');` because it is not visible.

you should php-filetype call into it the html-video-tag. this was an option otherwise you will get only errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a JavaScript script retrieved via AJAX, use `$.getScript()`.

```
function getusermedia() {
  $.getScript("getusermedia.js");
}
```

You're not passing an argument to `getusermedia()`, and the JS script doesn't use any parameters, so I've removed `media` from your function.